# dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator scaffolding controller : Primary key not found

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

Using netcoreapp3.1 (3.1.6 libraries) in VS Code

I have built a simple web api project, reverse engineered my database (`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`) which contains views that have no keys, which [shouldn't be a problem anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/).

I can see that in `onModelCreating` code is added to clarify that there is no key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VwAverageRuns>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();
```

The problem arises when I go to generate a controller:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name VwAverageRunsController -async -api -m VwAverageRuns -dc dbContext -outDir Controllers
```

It errors with:

> Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'VwAverageRuns'
> Primary key not found.
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b__6_0()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)

But from everything I've read, the `hasNoKey()` inside `onModelCreating` should mean that I don't need to specify a key. What's going on here?